# Can't update git to use access token instead of password

Tags: git, macos, github

I'm trying to update my `git` settings (on macOS Big Sur) to use a personal access token for GitHub, instead of a username and password.

I have followed all the [instructions](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/using-git/caching-your-github-credentials-in-git) and installed the `osxkeychain` helper. Then:

```
 git config --global credential.helper osxkeychain
```

> The next time you clone an HTTPS URL that requires authentication, Git will prompt you for your username and password. When Git prompts you for your password, enter your personal access token (PAT) instead.

Sadly, these instructions seem incorrect. Git keeps using my name and password and doesn't ask for the new Personal Access Token. How can I fix this?

Comment: ***When Git prompts you for your password**, enter your personal access token (PAT) **instead.*** It's clear enough.

Comment: Yes, but that doesn't happen... that's why I posted this question 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's likely that you were already using this credential manager, since it's the default for most distributions of macOS and your password is already saved.

To remove the password in your credential manager so you'll be prompted again, follow [the directions outlined in the Git FAQ](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitfaq#Documentation/gitfaq.txt-HowdoIchangethepasswordortokenI8217vesavedinmycredentialmanager):

```
$ echo url=https://bk2204@github.com | git credential reject
```

You will of course want to replace my username with yours.

Comment: Thanks, now it did ask for the new password. But if I open Keychain, I don't see it anywhere. How can I be sure the access token is added to keychain? (especially since the access token is not visible on GitHub anymore after generating it)

Comment: If it prompts you for it again, it's not saved; otherwise, it is.  I don't have a Mac at hand so I can't tell you where to look, but I know there are several keychains and it may not be in the default one.